# Vue JS Components structure

Tags: vue.js, components, emit

I am learning Vue and my doubt is about the structure of my Vue app.

I learnt that the components can include both logic and template. Then I separated my components and everyone is getting the config from the main app  (config is an object with the coordinates config.ll, config.lng).

I do the ajax call to my search-and-discovery API service and I display the results inside each components (current location, venues-near-you etc).

My question is: is it correct to encapsulate the calls into each components? Or is it better to get the needed data inside the general app and then share the results with the components using pros?

I am asking that because the hard part is starting now when I want to communicate the click of a category to the venuesNearYou component, I tried to use the emit without success.

```
//MAIN
<sidebar :config="config"></sidebar>
<content :config="config"></content>

//IN SIDEBAR
<currentLocation :config="config"></currentLocation>
<categories :config="config"></categories>

//IN CONTENT
<venueDetails :config="config"></venueDetails>
<venuesNearYou :config="config"></venuesNearYou>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use event Bus like approach
we have three type of communication in vue app (without vuex)

- Parent to child communication which is full field by props
- child to parent communication handle by custom event from child which is listen by parent
- communication between non parent child component in which we use event bus approach
  Parent to child example
- 

Child to parent example

- In child this.$emit('sendDataToParent',{someData:"some data"}})
- in parent
  <child-component :somedata="dataToChild" @sendDataToParent="'gotsomedata from parent'">

Event Bus
in main vue instance
const eventBus = new Vue()

in some component from where to send data
import eventBus
eventBus.$emit('someEvent','some data')

in some component from where to receive data

```
created() {
// register listener
  eventBus.$on('someEvent',()=>{
```

})
}

For more reference
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event
https://medium.com/easyread/vue-as-event-bus-life-is-happier-7a04fe5231e1

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bhavesh ! I read all the Vue documentation and I implemented an Event Bus. I've been able to manage communication between components. It's a monolithic file for now so next step will be to separate components into separated files. https://github.com/gmaccario/vuesquare/blob/master/public/js/foursquare-vue.js

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you around emitting an event since you didn't provide much of a code. But check [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).  It serves as a centralized store for all the components in Vue application.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I am reading your link and I found that: "if your app is simple, you will most likely be fine without Vuex. A simple store pattern may be all you need." And this is my case since I am just learning Vue and I am creating a simple app. But your suggestion could be useful in the future!

Comment: Sooner or later you will start using Vuex :) Can you provide more code about your existing problem?

Comment: The code is a bunch of attributes and methods and I am trying to figured out how to organize it. When the app starts I'll pass the config to the categories component and the idea was to populate the categories, consuming the API inside the component. I am able to do it and it's fine. But when I click a categories I need to changes the venues, another component. My assumption of single components with specific methods encapsulated doesn't work anymore, then I need a more general object where modify the lists. In this simple app probably a store pattern could help me, thoughts?